# Fix range when combining plots

Tags: graphics

Is there a way to automatically choose the y-axes when combining plots (and in passing, why isn't that the default behaviour for Show[ plot1, plot2 ]?)

```
 bidPlotZoom    = Plot[ bid[u], {u, 0, 20000 }, PlotStyle -> Blue ]
 askPlotZoom    = Plot[ ask[u], {u, 0, 20000 }, PlotStyle -> Green ]

 Show[ askPlotZoom, bidPlotZoom ]
```

[image: screenshot]

Actually I'd settle for a manual way right now :)

Comment: Somehow WRI decided to mention that not earlier but in the last section of docs for `Show`. Show takes options from the first graphic.

Comment: Thanks. Still wondering why PlotRange -> Automatic isn't the default, but I'm sure there is a reason.

Comment: yup, that would be a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Argh. It was just

```
Show[  , PlotRange-> Automatic ]
```